# Allow only Cloudflare traffic in .htaccess by denying all traffic with no CF-RAY header present

Tags: .htaccess, cloudflare

For security reasons I want to restrict in .htaccess all traffic that is not coming via Cloudflare. I have already script that blocks all non Cloudflare IPs but on some hostings it just doesn't work. I want to check if request header contains header CF-RAY, regardless of value, and if not, return 403 error.
Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try with:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-RAY} ^$
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

Comment: This is "security through obscurity", which offers no real protection. Regular users will be coming through Cloudflare anyway. It's only attackers that would be trying to bypass Cloudflare, and they would know to add that header to any malicious requests.

Comment: it's not safe. it can pass easily with a header.

Answer (score 2):

If it is for security reasons using a header is dangerous. It is effortless to send you this header from another source.

It is better to restrict by IP to requests from CloudFlare
https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/

If it is Apache you can add something like this in .htaccess

```
deny from all
allow from ... (one row for every range in above url)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yeah this is super easy to do by placing this in the top of your .htaccess file

```
#apache_2.4_cloudflare_bypass_protection_htaccess
#Place in top of .htaccess in document root that needs protected
#
## References
#https://docs.sucuri.net/website-firewall/configuration/prevent-sucuri-firewall-bypass/
#https://docs.sucuri.net/website-firewall/troubleshooting/bypassing-firewall-for-testing/
#https://community.cloudflare.com/t/prevent-users-bypassing-cloudflare-to-access-my-site/4606
#https://blog.christophetd.fr/bypassing-cloudflare-using-internet-wide-scan-data/
#https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/
#https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/204899617

# BEGIN Cloudflare Firewall Bypass Prevention
#Apache 2.4 Server
<FilesMatch ".*">
    Require ip 173.245.48.0/20
    Require ip 103.21.244.0/22
    Require ip 103.22.200.0/22
    Require ip 103.31.4.0/22
    Require ip 141.101.64.0/18
    Require ip 108.162.192.0/18
    Require ip 190.93.240.0/20
    Require ip 188.114.96.0/20
    Require ip 197.234.240.0/22
    Require ip 198.41.128.0/17
    Require ip 162.158.0.0/15
    Require ip 104.16.0.0/12
    Require ip 172.64.0.0/13
    Require ip 131.0.72.0/22
    Require ip 2400:cb00::/32
    Require ip 2606:4700::/32
    Require ip 2803:f800::/32
    Require ip 2405:b500::/32
    Require ip 2405:8100::/32
    Require ip 2a06:98c0::/29
    Require ip 2c0f:f248::/32
#    Allow from INSERT YOUR IP HERE
</FilesMatch>
# END Cloudflare Firewall Bypass Prevention
```

Full disclaimer: I have a git repo full of premade ones for Sucuri/Cloudflare for Openlitespeed/Litespeed/Apache.
https://gitlab.com/mikeramsey/apache-htaccess-rules/-/tree/master/